# How to set filters for convoltional neural network

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, classification, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build a multi class image classifier using keras cnn. My input size of images is (256,256) pixels. But i used (128,128) instead, since it will take a lot of time to process (256,256)pixel images. But when i test the network with test set i barely get 50% accuracy although  i get 97% accuracy during training. I think there is a problem with filters or number of layers. can anyone explain how to improve the efficiency of my cnn based classifier.

I tried changing number of epoches, i used input shape as (64,64) but these are producing small effects.

...`enter code here`

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Conv2D
from keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import Flatten
from keras.layers import Dropout
import os


classifier = Sequential()

classifier.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), input_shape = (128,128,3), activation = "relu"))

classifier.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), input_shape = (128,128,3), activation = "relu"))

classifier.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3), input_shape = (128,128,3), activation = "relu"))

classifier.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3), input_shape = (128,128,3), activation = "relu"))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))



classifier.add(Flatten())
classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))
classifier.add(Dense(units= 64, activation = "relu"))

classifier.add(Dense(units= 6, activation = "softmax"))

classifier.compile(optimizer = "adam", loss = "categorical_crossentropy", metrics = ['accuracy'])



from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
rescale=1./255,
shear_range=0.2,
zoom_range=0.2,
horizontal_flip=True)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale = 1./255)
training_set = train_datagen.flow_from_directory("/home/user/Documents/final_year_project/dataset/training",
target_size = (128,128),
batch_size = 50,
class_mode="categorical")

test_set = test_datagen.flow_from_directory(
"/home/user/Documents/final_year_project/dataset/testing/",
target_size = (128,128),
batch_size = 32,
class_mode="categorical")


from IPython.display import display
from PIL import Image

classifier.fit_generator(training_set, steps_per_epoch=98, epochs=18)

target_dir = '/home/user/Documents/model'
if not os.path.exists(target_dir):
os.mkdir(target_dir)
classifier.save('/home/user/Documents/model/model.h5')
classifier.save_weights('/home/user/Documents/model/weights.h5')

print("Training Completed!!")
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of obvious improvements (to me) that you can do:

Change batch size to 2 ** n (i.e. 2 to the power of 5: batch_size = 32).

`input_shape` is reserved for your input layer only (first convolutional layer).

```
classifier = Sequential()

# Add extraction layers.
classifier.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), input_shape = (128,128,3), 
               activation="relu"))
classifier.add(Conv2D(64,(3,3), activation="relu"))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))     # <= this may help as well
classifier.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation="relu"))
classifier.add(Conv2D(32,(3,3), activation="relu"))
classifier.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2,2)))

# Add classifier layers.
classifier.add(Flatten()) 
classifier.add(Dropout(0.5))        # might be too big, can try 0.2
classifier.add(Dense(units=64, activation="relu"))
classifier.add(Dense(units=6, activation="softmax"))

classifier.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="categorical_crossentropy", 
                   metrics = ['accuracy'])
```

**MOST IMPORTANT:** Add validation data to your training. The training:validation ratio is roughly 80:20.

```
fit_generator(
    generator,              # *
    steps_per_epoch=None,   # **
    epochs=20,
    verbose=1,
    callbacks=None,
    validation_data=None,   # same format as training generator *
    validation_steps=None,  # same format as steps_per_epoch    **
    class_weight=None,
    max_queue_size=10,
    workers=1,
    use_multiprocessing=False,
    shuffle=True,
    initial_epoch=0
)
```

Comment: can you explain more about input shape. Because my system is hanging with high input shape.

Comment: can you please explain about validation? I cant understand what you have said.